# Reading one file at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have the following code to look for new files in the directory:

```
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\temp\Dir1\";
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and the `OnChanged` event handler:

```
            public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {           
                 Thread t = new Thread(readFile);
                 t.Start(e.FullPath);
            }
```

and the `readFile` thread method:

```
            public void readFile(){
                 FSReader vsfr = new FSReader((string)path);
                 while (vsfr.EndOfStream == false)
                 {
                    PrintLine(vsfr.ReadLine());
                 }
                 vsfr.Close();
            }
```

So every time a new file is created, it's being read by `readFile` thread. The problem occurs when the first file is being read and the second file starts to be read by another thread.

What I need is **first thread to get terminated when the second thread opens** so there's only a single thread running at a time to read a single file. I know that I need to use lock and events to accomplish this.

When I use `lock` on the `readFile` method, I get the desired result of a single thread running at once, but I still need a way to tell the previous thread to close, when new thread opens. How can I do this?

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Google for co-operative cancellation

Comment: I have to use threads

Comment: This is the mere beginning of your problems... Ignoring any threading issues, what happens if the file is still being written to when you open it and try to read from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty easy, just add a lock when you reading files and some simple cancelation

```
string _path;
Thread
object _lock = new object();
volatile bool _running;
volatile bool _cancel;

public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{   
    // waiting
    while(_running)
    {
        _cancel = true;
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
    // start new thread
    _cancel = false;
    _path = e.FullPath;
    (new Thread(ReadFile)).Start();
}

public void ReadFile()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        _running = true;
        using(var reader = new FSReader(_path))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                if(_cancel)
                    break;
                PrintLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        _running = false;
    }
}
```

I assume, you  want to have only **1 thread working at a time**.

When creating a new thread, you have to check if it is already running and if is, then set cancel and wait for it to finish.

It is possible to keep `Thread` instance and check `IsAlive` instead of using `_running`.

You could use `Task` instead of `Thread`. You can use `ManualResetEvent` to avoid need for a sleep, though in this scenario `Sleeps` looks harmless to me.

### Edit

Let's play with it

```
volatile bool _cancel;
Mutex _mutext = new Mutex(false);

public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    _cancel = true;
    _mutex.WaitOne();
    // start new thread
    _cancel = false;
    _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    (new Thread(ReadFile)).Start(e.FullPath);
}

public void ReadFile(string path)
{
    _mutex.WaitOne();
    using(var reader = new FSReader(path))
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            if(_cancel)
                break;
            PrintLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Now we are using `Mutex` to ensure, what no new thread will be started, until existing (if any) will finish its work. No need for `lock` (mutex do all the job).

### Edit

Actually, there is a slim but chance, what if `OnChanged` will be called **before** thread takes mutex ownership (it's possible in theory), then we are in trouble.

Solution would be to implementing sort of *ping-pong* waiting between thread and event (two mutexes, or perhaps some other synchronization primitive).

Comment: that solves the first problem, but now I have another problem. I have to wait for the first file to be read and only then the second thread will open and start to read the second file. If a new file is created while the first file is being read, I need first file to close and then create a second thread and start reading the new file. Thanks

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes, but maybe i didn't understand it. And `static` to make sure what *everything* what is trying to use `PrintLine` is locked (there could be multiple watchers). Though this is not known and you are right, it could be not necessary or even **bad**.

Comment: @Sinatr Can you please show the the same example using 'ManualResetEvent' please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something along these lines.  Obviously add your own locks/synchronisation.

```
while (vsfr.EndOfStream == false)
{
  if (cancelThread)
  {
     vsfr.Close()
     return;
  }
  PrintLine(vsfr.ReadLine());
}
```

and

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{           
   Thread t = new Thread(readFile);
   //If a thread is running, set the cancellation flag = true
   //If you have some class-level reference to the running thread, you can then wait for it to .Join()
   //Set cancellation flag back to false
   t.Start(e.FullPath);
}
```